# Adjustment algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am trying to find a function in Matlab, or at least the name of an algorithm that does the following:

Let's say that I am analyzing a time series in real time. I initially start with a threshold of 10 and -10, so that when the time series goes above 10 or below -10, it's considered a 'HIT'. Let's say it initially takes the time series 5 minutes to produce a 'HIT', but I want to adjust the threshold so that, on average, it takes only 1 minute for a 'HIT' to be produced. I know it would look something like start with 10 and -10, if it takes too long, drop it to 5 and -5, then increase the threshold if it's too quick, etc.

I know there's a specific name for this type of algorithm, and there's probably built-in functions for this, but the name is eluding me. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the time resolution of your time series is, or if it's constant, so I'll leave that to you. However here is what you can do in matlab if you have a constant time resolution. First take the absolute value of the values in your time series. Then sort these values in reverse order using the `sort()` command. Then choose the value whose index in the sorted array gives you the average time resolution that you desire. So e.g. if your time series has size N and the time resolution is 0.1 seconds, and you want an alert on average every 1 second, then after sorting you would choose the threshold at (reverse order) sorted position N/10.

Comment: It is indeed constant. Is there a name for this method? I'm assuming reverse order would be descending (since Matlab default is ascending)?

Comment: ^^^ Sorry to bug you again. Been doing some Googling, and can't really find any information on this method. I was wondering if there is a formal name for this type of adaptive thresholding.

Comment: Would I simply sort in ascending order if I want a negative threshold?